# Create a data structure with object at index 0 of an array

Tags: javascript

I want to add an object to an array at specific index: this is my existing  structure:

```
let a = {
    "tt" : ["test"],
    "tt4": [
      "the test44",
      "the test55"
    ]
}
```

and this is what I want to achieve:

```
let a = {
    "tt" : ["test"],
    "tt4": [ {key: "the test44", gptest: "e732iry"}, "the test55" ]
}
```

However its giving me an "Unexpected identifier" at the "the test44"? Ho can I create an object with the above structure?

Comment: What you want isn't valid syntax.

Comment: [You seem to be confusing JavaScript with JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Arrays don't have keys. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming your desired output is an array as follow:**

```
[ {key: "the test44", gptest: "e732iry"}, "the test55" ]
```

You can use the function `map`.

*This approach will find a specific target, even if this is repeated multiple times within the current array.*

```js
let a = {"tt": ["test"],"tt4": ["the test44","the test55"]},
    target = "the test44";
   
a.tt4 = a.tt4.map((t) => t === target ? {[t]: t, gptest: "e732iry"} : t);
console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That targets any element equal to `"the test44"`, not index 0 of an array.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to structure it like this:

```
let a = {
    "tt" : ["test"],
    "tt4": [
      {
       "the test44":
           {
             key: "the test44", 
             gptest: "e732iry"
           }
      },
      "the test55"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't answer *how* to create that structure via code.

Comment: Why not `[ "the test44", { key: "the test44", gptest: "e732iry" }, "the test55" ]`?

Comment: since this will create another element in that array and I'm not looking to add elements in the array